# wait for the pod to be ready

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-pod, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to add a step in the pipeline where a check is made if the PODS are ready before the pipeline moves forward.
I've read on forums that the `kubectl wait` command can work, however, every time the pipeline is executed, the PODS are created again, so I can't put a default name on the kubectl wait command.
Does anyone have any tips, please?

Comment: Are your pods part of a deployment?

Comment: yes
they're part

Comment: Can I adapt this command so that it validates the pods in a namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pods are part of a deployment:

```
kubectl wait deployment <deployment-name> -n <deployment-namespace> --for condition=Available=True --timeout=120s
```